# Finding the distance of a line segment that cuts a right triangle in half

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Lets say I have a 3,4,5 right triangle:

[image]

How would I find the value of x?

This isn't a homework problem. It's just been a while since I've had to do this kind of math.

Comment: Does have $x$ some property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the area of the original triangle is 6.  The area of the small triangle on the bottom must be 3; the base is 3 so the height must be 2.

The equation of the hypotenuse is $y = -\frac{4}{3}x + 4$  Since the height is 2, solve
$$2 = -\frac{4}{3}x + 4$$ and you have your $(x,y)$ of the meeting point.  Then easily do 
the length by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

The answer will be a nice fraction, but not an integer.

Comment: If the height was found to be 2, by similar triangles or by the converse of midpoint theorem, the height divides the base (of length 3) into two equal halves. Thus, x is given by $\sqrt (2^2 + (\frac {3}{2})^2)$.